# Incorrect values fron Input.GetAxis

Tags: unity

I need the gamepad Input on my game, and I'm trying the Input.getAxis("Horizontal") function and the documentation says that returns a value from -1 to 1, 0 is the central value, when I not move the stick left or right. Well, I'm on linux-editor on mint 17.3 and all is ok, the joystick configuration on mint is correct, but in Unity I having a 0 to maximum stick move to left and 1 to maximum stick moved to right on my gamepad (logitech rumblepad2). Center is 0.56.

What is the problem?? Is a linux editor problem, is a bad Unity configuration...

Comment: Could you post the Unity configuration you're using?

Comment: Input configuration?

Comment: what do you mean by "top left moved" and "top right moved"? That confuses me greatly.

Comment: Yes, top-left and top-right I mean when I move the stick at the maximum at right or left. My english is limited xD...I edited the question. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably caused by the drivers in your connected gamepad. It seems that the values are on the right side of the Cartesian plane, which is different to how Unity processes input.